# Where do I find this related list API name to access in query?

Tags: soql, query, related-list, childrelationship

I have a related list on my Contracts for Orders. I am querying for certain contracts, and I want to Select ID, startdate, and some other fields, along with its corresponding related list of orders. I've seen some code for grabbing related lists, but I can't seem to find what the list API name is, or correct syntax from other forums for something to work. Can somebody step me through this, starting from where I find the related list API name? I think I recall going to 'fields' one time in the past and seeing other relationships there, but not in this case now.

update:

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can *always* find the child relationship name by going through the `DescribeSObjectResult` on your parent object.

```
DescribeSObjectResult describe = SObjectType.Contract;
for (ChildRelationship relation : describe.getChildRelationships())
{
    system.debug(relation);
}
```

You can just filter this debug log for `Order` (case-sensitive) and you will find the relationship you are looking for. You want the value in `getRelationshipName`.

If you wanted to use the `Contract` and `Order` standard objects, you would do:

```
for (ChildRelationship relation : SObjectType.Contract.getRelationships())
    if (relation.childSObject() == Order.sObjectType)
        system.debug(relation.getRelationshipName());
```

If that script outputs `Orders`, then you would do:

```
List<Contract> contractsWithOrders = [
    SELECT StartDate, (SELECT Id FROM Orders)
    FROM Contract WHERE ...
];
```

Comment: Thanks! I found the relationship name. It is "Orders", which is what I used in my query before (Orders__r) from another source, and it didn't seem syntactically correct. Now that I have this part verified, how do I go about querying for it when querying for contracts?

Comment: What do contracts have to do with orders?

Comment: See question: I have a related list on my Contracts for Orders

I am trying to pull this related list along with other fields on the Contracts I'm querying

Comment: @NatalieSpatharakis - No __r, I was incorrect in my previous edit. Simply use `From Orders` in the subquery. To tell you exactly, we will need to see some code or better understand what you are trying to query

Comment: That's what I'm trying to find out, how to do a "subquery". I do not understand how to pull a related list from an object in a query

Comment: @NatalieSpatharakis You pull in the relationship name verbatim. See my query example at the end.

Answer (score 4):

**Declarative (Standard Order Object)**

1. Setup
2. Customize
3. Orders
4. Click on the field that is the lookup to the Contract
5. Look at the Child Relationship name

For code see Adrian's answer

An example query

```
[
 Select Id, ....., 
    (Select Id, ...... From Orders) 
 From Contract
]
```

Comment: Caveat that this approach doesn't provide the namespace.

Comment: There is no "Orders" under customize -- see edited question for screenshot. Thoughts?

Comment: @NatalieSpatharakis Is orders a custom object `Orders__c` If so goto Create -> Objects. Also, the list under customize is not in alphabetical order. you can type Order in the search box to find it if not custom

Comment: Orders are standard objects

Comment: Then it will be under the customize list. In my org is is right under Contracts

Answer (score 0):

You can use Schema describe to get all of the child relationship API names:

```
String[] sObjTypes = new String[]{'Contract'};
Schema.DescribeSObjectResult[] describeSObjResults = Schema.describeSObjects(sObjTypes);
for(Schema.DescribeSObjectResult dsr : describeSObjResults) {
    for(Schema.ChildRelationship cr : dsr.getChildRelationships()) {
        system.debug( 'sObject: ' + dsr.getName() + ' - Child Relationship API Name: ' + cr.getRelationshipName());
    }
}
```

Then to for the subquery to grab all related Orders to contracts:

```
[SELECT Id, (SELECT Id FROM Orders) FROM Contract]
```

Comment: Appreciate the effort but the answer does not provide anything additional to what Adrian posted. It actually adds unnecessary code. If you feel it adds to the previous answer can you please clarify the benefits of the additional code

Comment: I felt it would be useful to know you could get the describe information for multiple sObjects at the same time. Also, it doesn't sound like the OP is planning on actually using this in code, rather just to retrieve the API names as needed. I didn't see the latest edits from Adrian's post, I can remove my post if its not useful.